# Determining the state of this BJT transistor

Tags: bjt

My question is about the state of Q2 in the following circuit.

[image]

For the above differential amplifier a text says when Vin1=+1V and Vin2=-1V, the transistor Q1 will be active but Q2 will be in cutoff.
I'm having a bit confusion for this conclusion.

If I start thinking first from Q1 then I can say that since Vbe1=0.7V the voltage at point A=1-0.7=+0.3V.
This means since Vin2=-1, Vbe2 is reverse biased hence the Q2 is in cutoff.

But if I initially start thinking from Q2 then I can say that initially Vin2=-1V and Vee=-9V, hence Vbe2 is forward biased and the transistor Q2 is active.

Where am I logically wrong here?

Comment: **If** point A was 0.7V below Q2 emitter as you are suggesting then this would attempt to produce a voltage drop of **2V across the base-emitter of Q1** which is clearly wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first explanation, starting with Q1 is correctly describing the state of the circuit.

*But if I initially start thinking from Q2 then I can say that initially Vin2=-1V and Vee=-9V, hence Vbe2 is forward biased and the transistor Q2 is active.*

This is indeed incorrect as it ignores the fact that **a current is coming out of the emitter of Q1**. So much current that the voltage across RE becomes more than the 7.3 V (or less) needed to keep the Base-Emitter junction of Q2 in forward mode.

Your explanation would be correct only if there was no current coming out of Q1. But there is and so much in fact that the common emitter rail (point A) is pulled up so much that Q2 ends up being cut off.

Comment: I still dont understand well, but maybe you might comment on what I think. Again I initially start thinking from Q2, then the voltage at A becomes -1-0.7 = -1.7V. This means at first both Q1 and Q2 is active. But for that to be true Vbe1 should be 1V-(-1.7V)=2.7V. We know that Vbe1 cannot be 2.7V it has to be 0.7V in active region. So we cancel this. Is this a correct way to prove starting from Q2 is wrong?

Comment: Sure you can look at it that way but a better approach is to understand how a "differential pair" works. When I see the circuit and see that there's 2 V across the input I already know that one NPN will be on and the other one will be off. It takes less than 0.1 V voltage difference to force one of the transistors in cut-off.

Answer (score 0):

> But if I initially start thinking from Q2 then I can say that
>   initially Vin2=-1V and Vee=-9V, hence Vbe2 is forward biased and the
>   transistor Q2 is active.

You have forgotten to take account of Q1 as the condition for it to operate in OFF state must fulfill. To understand which is on and which is in off state you could make four separate assumptions and see which works out:

Assumption 1:

**Q1 is ON and Q2 is off**. This makes sense because if Q1 is ON then the voltage at A will be 1-0.7=0.3V. This ensures that Q2 is reversed biased and in OFF state. So this works out pretty well.

Maybe there is now no need for the other assumptions to make as we've already figured it out. But anyway here's the other assumptions where your confusion lie.

Assumption 2

**Q1 is OFF and Q2 is ON**. This means that the voltage at A is -1.7V. But that makes things on Q1's part a bit messy. The Q1's base-emitter junction has now 1--1.7=2.7V on it. That's wrong and can't happen.

Assumption 3

**Both Q1 and Q2 are ON**. This can't happen with the arrangement. As the voltage at node A must be both 0.3V and -1.7V at the same time, which is completely illogical.

Assumption 4

**Both Q1 and Q2 are OFF**. This also doesn't happen. Because for that to occur one thing that should hold is that the voltage at node A be way greater than 1.7V. But this implies that there is now a current through Re because of the voltage difference across it. This current has to follow through a path, and this path includes one of these transistors, which means at least one of these transistors is on. But this doesn't agree with our assumption so the fourth assumption will be invalid.

Therefore we conclude that Q1 is in ON state and Q2 in OFF state. In reality we try to make a more educated guess than the last three guesses I made above. I made Assumption 1 as my first guess and checked it out and saw that it worked well.

\end